# Request Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Ola preciso guardar os valores da variavel $result em uma sessao, segue o codigo.

```
class CorreioController extends Controller
{

    public function calculate(Request $request)
    {
     
             
     $params = array(
        'nCdEmpresa'=>NUll,
        'sDsSenha'=>NULL,
        'sCepOrigem'=>14942020,   
        'sCepDestino'=>$_POST['sCepDestino'],
        'nVlPeso' =>$_POST['nVlPeso'],
        'nCdFormato' =>'1',
        'nVlComprimento' =>15,
        'nVlAltura' =>15,
        'nVlLargura' =>15,
        'sCdMaoPropria' => 'n',
        'nVlValorDeclarado' => '0',
        'sCdAvisoRecebimento' => 'n',
        'nCdServico' => $_POST['nCdServico'],
        'nVlDiametro' => '0',            
        'StrRetorno' => 'xml',
        'nIndicaCalculo' => '3'
     );
        $url = ('http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx?') . http_build_query($params);
        $c = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $fact = curl_exec($c);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($fact);
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        $result = json_decode($json, true);

    }
   
}
```

Pois,gostaria de reutilizar esses valores em uma view.

Comment: Não é mais fácil você simplesmente chamar a view que precisa com a variável nela? Você pode fazer isto no controlle com: return view('nomeDaView',compact('variavel1','variavel2','variavelN'));

Comment: **Nota:** para converter o XML para array basta fazer `$result = (array) $xml`, não precisa converter para JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode guardar valores na session do php com a função `session(['chave' => 'valor ou variavel']);` e recuperar eles com a `session()->get('chave')`, porém não se confunda com as sessoes do php e da view, a mesma sessão q está no php é apenas do php, não tem nada a ver com a função sessionStorage do Js.
No seu caso você poderia apenas armazenar tudo numa váriavel e retornar para view com `compact()`. Por exemplo... Controller:

```
$variavel = [
                'nome' => 'João',
                'sobrenome' => 'Silva'
            ];

return view('view...')
            ->with(compact('variavel'));
```

No blade:

```
O nome do usuário é {{ $variavel['nome'] . ' '  . $variavel['sobrenome']}}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado eu realmente precisava do valor guardado na sessao. Sua resposta me ajudou muito, pois eu n sabia como acessar os valores armazenados